# html image src call javaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code: I want to ask

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var total = 4;

</script>
```

How can I do this?

```
<img src="img/apple_" + total + ".png" id="imageBox"/>
```

I've been try to use call function and document.onload but it's not work at all, can somebody save me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am supposing you just want to update the image src with javascript.

```
document.getElementById('imageBox').src = "img/apple_" + total + ".png";
```

Comment: Ok thank you for reminding me, I was putting my javascript code under the html so it will load it

Answer (score 5):

You need to add html in JavaScript like this:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var total = 4;
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = '<img src="img/apple_' + total + '.png" id="imageBox"/>';
</script>
```

Comment: why using div? but Im using <img/>

Comment: the div need to be before the script or code inside onload event, otherwise getElementById will not find the #foo element.

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var total = 4;
  document.getElementById('imageBox').src = 'img/apple_' + total + '.png"';

};
```

```html
<img src="" id="imageBox"/>
```

Comment: where to put the window.onload?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean way to do this.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p6mLm834/)

```
var create_img_element = function(total, targetId){
    //create the img element
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    //set the source of the image
    img.src = 'img/apple_' + total + '.png';
    //add the image to a specific element
    document.getElementById(targetId).appendChild(img);
}

create_img_element(5, 'foo');
```