# Using javascript date variable link in html

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I want to add this code in a custom HTML widget of wordpress website but the problem is that I am unable to create and use date-wise image link. By seeing the code below, please tell me what is wrong here and how to correct it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var today = yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+'dd';
var link = "http://e.piyarawatan.com/paper/" + today + "p-1.jpg";

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src='<script type=javascript>link</script>'>aaa</img>
</body>
</html>
```

The output should be an image but it is not. Here the the output:

aaa

After compiling, the image goes to this link : 
http://news.piyarawatan.com/%3Cscript%20type=javascript%3Elink%3C/script%3E
which is an invalid link

Comment: You tell us what's the problem.

Comment: I edited. check the last lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference a JS variable like that in HTML.  You need to give the image tag an id, and dynamically set the src attribute of this element. Like so:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if(dd<10){
      dd='0'+dd;
  } 
  if(mm<10){
      mm='0'+mm;
  } 
  var today = yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd;
  var link = "http://e.piyarawatan.com/paper/" + today + "/p-1.jpg";
  console.log (link)

  document.getElementById("image1").src = link;
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<image id="image1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the edit I made fixes the link to match what looks right for this site (http://e.piyarawatan.com/paper/2018/03/01/p8.htm), but there isnt an image for today, so it isnt going to work

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var today = yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+'dd';
```

should be:

```
var path = yyyy+'/'+ mm +'/'+ dd + '/';
```

Don't re-declare `today`, use a new variable instead for clarity.  Then the next line should read:

```
var link = "http://e.piyarawatan.com/paper/" + path + "p-1.jpg";
```

Finally, you aren't interpolating here correctly either:

```
<img src='<script type=javascript>link</script>'>aaa</img>
```

One way to do this is:

```
document.write('<img src="' + link + '" />');
```

inside your `script` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question: [html image src call javaScript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149719/html-image-src-call-javascript-variable)